# How do I update individual/multiple packages in local redhat/centos repo without syncing whole repo

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm, yum

Is there a way to update individual/multiple packages in a local RedHat/CentOS repo without doing a sync on the entire repo?

We have local repo setup and it is set to reposync quarterly, but we want to be able to update individual packages as well as dependencies they require without having to do a reposync on the whole repo.

Is this possible in a less than insanely manual way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yumdownloader --destdir DIR --resolve package1 package2
```